# Handle large messages with Apache Camel and AMQ Artemis

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-artemis

When I receive a large message (100KiB+) in a AMQ Artemis Queue and try to route this message to another AMQ and this message have the property `_AMQ_LARGE_SIZE` I got the follow error:

```
14:38:56.250 [Camel (CamelTestRoute) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[QUEUE.TEST]] WARN  o.a.c.c.jms.EndpointMessageListener - Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: Invalid address QUEUE.TEST]
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: Invalid address QUEUE.TEST
```

I know if I set the property `minLargeMessageSize` in the Connection Factory that post the message in AMQ, this problem does not happens.

The problem is,  I don't have control of the codes that create the Connection Factories, and some times they don't set the Large Message Size property.

Is there a way that can I handle this in Camel with my Connection Factory?

*EDIT

```
16:33:03.836 [Camel (CamelTestRoute) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[QUEUE.TEST]] WARN  o.a.c.c.jms.EndpointMessageListener - Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: Invalid address QUEUE.TEST]
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: Invalid address QUEUE.TEST
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1830)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener$EndpointMessageListenerAsyncCallback.done(EndpointMessageListener.java:196)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:117)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:719)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:649)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1168)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1160)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1057)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: Invalid address QUEUE.TEST
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQDestination.fromAddress(ActiveMQDestination.java:119)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessage.getJMSDestination(ActiveMQMessage.java:386)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.extractHeadersFromJms(JmsBinding.java:187)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsMessage.populateInitialHeaders(JmsMessage.java:229)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessage.createHeaders(DefaultMessage.java:257)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsMessage.ensureInitialHeaders(JmsMessage.java:214)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsMessage.getHeader(JmsMessage.java:164)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessage.getHeader(DefaultMessage.java:93)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork.<init>(DefaultUnitOfWork.java:115)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.MDCUnitOfWork.<init>(MDCUnitOfWork.java:54)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWorkFactory.createUnitOfWork(DefaultUnitOfWorkFactory.java:32)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$UnitOfWorkProcessorAdvice.createUnitOfWork(CamelInternalProcessor.java:695)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$UnitOfWorkProcessorAdvice.before(CamelInternalProcessor.java:663)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$UnitOfWorkProcessorAdvice.before(CamelInternalProcessor.java:634)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:149)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:113)
        ... 11 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Where does the `javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException: Invalid address QUEUE.TEST` originate? Is there a full stack-trace? I don't see that particular wording anywhere in the ActiveMQ Artemis code-base so I guess its coming from Camel itself. What is the other broker you're trying to route messages to? Is it also ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: Hi Betram, Yes I have, I'll update the question. I think the error come from Camel as well. Yes the second broker is the ActiveMQ Artemis, just hosted in another Network.

Comment: What version(s) of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: AMQ Artemis Version: 2.6.2
Apache Camel Version: 2.20.0

Comment: Are you sure you're using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.6.2? Looking at the source for ActiveMQDestination, [line 119](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.6.2/artemis-jms-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/client/ActiveMQDestination.java#L119) (where the exception is being thrown from) does not correspond to the method `fromAddress()`. This indicates to me that you're actually using a different version of Artemis.

Comment: It looks like you're using 1.5.6 where [ActiveMQDestination.java line 119](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/1.5.6/artemis-jms-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/client/ActiveMQDestination.java#L119) actually corresponds to what you're seeing.

Comment: Betram, you are right. I'm sorry. The version of AMQ is 2.6.2, But my Camel project are using 1.5.6 because your parent that was set to use the artemis-jms-client 1.5.6. Do you think this can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an Artemis 1.x client against an Artemis 2.x broker then you need to configure the acceptor that the client is connecting to with the appropriate `anycastPrefix` and `multicastPrefix`, e.g:

```
<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>
```

Comment: I have tested with 2.6.2, added the anycast and multicast prefix. Got the same behavior. After add ```connectionTtl``` in acceptor and add the option ```journal-buffer-size``` in broker.xml the problem was solved.